# Rmarkdown: Indentation of TOC items in HTML output

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to indent TOC according to header level.

My example document looks like this:

```
# Tutorial
## Start a new project
### Project structure
### Analysis code
```

I'm compiling `Rmd` document with:

```
rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", 
                  output_options = HTMLlook, 
                  output_file = "foo.html")

HTMLlook <- list(toc = TRUE,
                 toc_depth = 5,
                 toc_float = list(collapsed = FALSE, 
                                  smooth_scroll = TRUE))
```

This produces document with TOC

[image]

However, I want indented TOC (indentation equivalent to header level). **Wanted result** should look like this:
[image]

Is it possible to set this option in `render` or maybe pass css parameters to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*I am not aware of a built-in solution. But here is a little tweak:*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $items = $('div#TOC li');
      $items.each(function(idx) {
        num_ul = $(this).parentsUntil('#TOC').length;
        $(this).css({'text-indent': num_ul * 10, 'padding-left': 0});
      });

    });
</script>
```

The depth of your headers is actually mapped inside the `TOC`. For each level you go down, a new `ul` element is created. This is what we are making use of here. In detail:

When the document has finished loading (`$(document).ready(....`):

1. Select all list items inside the element with id `TOC`
2. For each list item count the number of parent elements until you reach the element with id `TOC`. This is the number of `ul` elements.
3. Change the style for the current list item according to the number of parents.

You can tweak the spacing by playing around with the two parameters for `text-indent` and `padding-left`.

---

**MRE:**

```
---
title: "Habits"
author: Martin Schmelzer
date: September 14, 2017
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 5
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: true
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $items = $('div#TOC li');
  $items.each(function(idx) {
    num_ul = $(this).parentsUntil('#TOC').length;
    $(this).css({'text-indent': num_ul * 10, 'padding-left': 0});
  });

});
</script>

# In the morning 

## Waking up 

### Getting up

#### Take a shower

##### Make coffee

# In the evening

## Make dinner
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: can that script be added to a pdf to get the same result? if so where in the pdf should it be placed?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is JavaScript, only applicable to HTML based documents.

Comment: I just tried this and the script is not doing anything. I also have an external css file being loaded as well - could that be causing problems? Also, could you give a general hint on how to include other dynamic css modifications like this, say changing font style or family? I tried to include a line: $(this).css({'font-style': normal}); to forcefully remove bold font of a toc sub-sub-heading (or all headings would be fine too). If I could get this to work, it would be a really cool solution. I can see how this is a very powerful idea!